# How to get intellisense working for Kendo UI?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, visual-studio-2013

I'm just starting out with a trial of Kendo UI (2014 Q1), in Visual Studio 2013.

I am following one of the walkthrough tutorials, and while the code runs fine, I'm not getting Intellisense for the Kendo objects the way I would expect.

[image]

Where's the secret switch to get intellisense working?

Comment: Old post and off topic, but what theme is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you verify that the kendo.web.min.intellisense.js file is present in the folder which hosts kendo.web.min.js? I used directions from [this topic](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/howto/vsdoc/vs-intellisense) for my kendo ui projects.

Comment: Ah, well, that would do it.  `kendo.web.min.intellisense.js` does not exist anywhere in my project.  Guess the scaffolding must have hit a bump somewhere.  Where can I find it?

Comment: Looking through the installation, I can't find that script, either.  Is it possible that the Q1-2014 release shipped without Intellisense!?

Comment: Found the intellisense files in the vsdoc file in the Kendo installation.  Copied it into the project folder with kendo.web.min.js, and now intellisense is working. TYVM!

Comment: The link in the post is dead, is it possible to get a working one ? Thanks