# How to use fluent interface for Kendo Grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Learning Kendo UI... I was playing with [this tutorial](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tutorials/asp.net/hello%20kendo%20ui/asp-net-hello-kendo-ui-part-2), which shows nicely how to set up a grid with server side paging using jQuery.

Now I'm trying to do the same thing, except using server-side script so I can use the nice Fluent interface (it seems that Kendo's 2014-Q1 release shipped without Intellisense - see comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22691150/7850)).  But I'm unable to get the grid to fire its first call to get data.  Here's what I have:

```
<div id="archiveGrid">
@(Html.Kendo()
      .Grid<MessageLite>()
      .Name("archives")
      .Columns(col =>
               {
                   col.Command(m => m.Custom("View").Click("viewClick")).Width(100);
                   col.Bound(m => m.SenderName).Title("Sender").Width(200);
                   col.Bound(m => m.SenderEmail).Title("Email").Width(200);
                   col.Bound(m => m.SentDate).Title("Sent").Format("{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm").Width(150);
                   col.Bound(m => m.Subject);
               })
      .Scrollable()
      .Pageable(pg => pg.PageSizes(true)
          .ButtonCount(10)
          .Input(true)
          .Refresh(true))
      .DataSource(ds => ds
          .Server()
          .PageSize(15)
          .Read(r=>r.Route("defaultApi").Action("","Messages")) // coming unstuck here, I think
          )
)

</div>
```

I'm trying to call the `ApiController` `MessagesController`, which has a `Get()` method.  In my routes definition I have this:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

... which works great when I'm using the jQuery syntax to call the Url `api/messages`, but it doesn't reach the server side at all when I use the Fluent syntax.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `Get` to your `.Action()`, like below:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<kendouimvcapplication1.models.albummodel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("Get", "Albums"))
    )
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
)
```

Comment: It doesn't like that.  My read is going to an `ApiController`, not a regular controller, so instead of routing to `api/messages`, it tries to route to `messages/get`, which doesn't work.  How do you invoke `read.Action()` to call an `ApiController`?

Comment: Have you looked at this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19863515/976042 ?

Comment: +1 Thanks!  That does appear to have helped, but I still have 2 problems: the grid does not refresh immediately on loading (which I want), and if I click the "refresh" button on the grid, it navigates the whole page to the Json result of the server call.  Obviously something else is configured wrong...

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that your binding is set to `Server()`.  Change that to `Ajax` as in my example above.

Comment: Nope, that didn't make any difference.  Still doesn't automatically load.

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser's console?  Can you post your APIs controller method?

Comment: No errors at all.  Fiddler corroborates: no attempt is being made to call the server side code, until I push the "refresh" button, at which point the whole browser navigates to display the Json result of the API method.

Comment: I've never seen it not refresh its data source on page load.  Do you have Telerik support?  This sounds like a possible question for them.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking the [Web Api editing](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/webapi-editing) tutorial which shows how to bind the Kendo UI Grid to Web API controller.